# Excel SUM IF with multiple array criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, sum, conditional-formatting

I am trying to do a "sum if" that checks whether the month and year are the same as the criteria on the income sheet column A as well verifying the income code in column D.

I have used the option with the * as the AND function.

I am using array formulae that work independently as I have shown below, but they fail when I try to get them to work together.

I cannot figure out how to calculate the desired result.

**Income summary table**

[image]

**Income table**

[image]

Please find working formulae as follows:

- Check Month and Year"

  - `=SUM(IF((MONTH(Income!$A$3:$A$10000)=MONTH($A3))*(YEAR(Income!$A$3:$A$10000)=YEAR($A3)),Income!$C$3:$C$10000))`
- Check Code

  - `=SUMIF(Income!$D$3:$D$10000,"="&$C$2,Income!$C$3:$C$10000)`

Please find non-working formulae as follows:

- `=SUM(IF((Income!$D$3:$D$10000*(MONTH(Income!$A$3:$A$10000)=MONTH($A3))*
  _(YEAR(Income!$A$3:$A$10000)=YEAR($A3),"="&$C$2)),Income!$C$3:$C$10000))`

I hope that somebody can help,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUM(IF((Income!$D$3:$D$10000=$C$2)*(MONTH(Income!$A$3:$A$10000)=MONTH($A3))*(YEAR(Income!$A$3:$A$10000)=YEAR($A3)),Income!$C$3:$C$10000,0))
```

You can also use this SUMPRODUCT variant:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Income!$D$3:$D$10000=$C$2),--(MONTH(Income!$A$3:$A$10000)=MONTH($A3)),--(YEAR(Income!$A$3:$A$10000)=YEAR($A3)),Income!$C$3:$C$10000)
```